# What are the languages supported by Web speech API?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

I plan to convert text to speech on certain events. What are the languages supported by the Web Speech API?

[Web speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)

Answer (score 3):

The voices supported depend on the browser and operating system. This has evolved over time as more voices are added.

I wrote a JSBin that displays a browser's voices in that OS: https://output.jsbin.com/dehoyavize

```js
"use strict";

/** Draw table from array of objects **/
const drawTable = (obArr, tableDiv) => {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  // Table header row
  const thr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (const p in obArr[0]) {
    // Get column headers from voice attributes
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p));
    thr.appendChild(th);
  }
  table.appendChild(thr);
  // Build rows
  for (const obj of obArr) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (const p in obj) {
      // Build table from each voice's attribute values
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[p]));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  };
  // Add table to document
  tableDiv.appendChild(table);
};

/** get w3c voices **/
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
  const tableDiv = document.querySelector('#tableDiv');
  let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  if (voices.length) {
    // Safari; FF caches voices after 1st load
    drawTable(voices, tableDiv);
  } else {
    // Opera win, Firefox 1st load, Chrome
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
      voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      drawTable(voices, tableDiv);
    };
  }
} else {
  // No window.speechSynthesis thus no voices
  // Opera android, etc.
  document.querySelector('#tableDiv').innerText = 'This browser has no voices';
}
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tableDiv">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In one old thread, I found the information that below languages are supported.

```
var langs =
[['Afrikaans',       ['af-ZA']],
 ['Bahasa Indonesia',['id-ID']],
 ['Bahasa Melayu',   ['ms-MY']],
 ['Català',          ['ca-ES']],
 ['Čeština',         ['cs-CZ']],
 ['Deutsch',         ['de-DE']],
 ['English',         ['en-AU', 'Australia'],
                     ['en-CA', 'Canada'],
                     ['en-IN', 'India'],
                     ['en-NZ', 'New Zealand'],
                     ['en-ZA', 'South Africa'],
                     ['en-GB', 'United Kingdom'],
                     ['en-US', 'United States']],
 ['Español',         ['es-AR', 'Argentina'],
                     ['es-BO', 'Bolivia'],
                     ['es-CL', 'Chile'],
                     ['es-CO', 'Colombia'],
                     ['es-CR', 'Costa Rica'],
                     ['es-EC', 'Ecuador'],
                     ['es-SV', 'El Salvador'],
                     ['es-ES', 'España'],
                     ['es-US', 'Estados Unidos'],
                     ['es-GT', 'Guatemala'],
                     ['es-HN', 'Honduras'],
                     ['es-MX', 'México'],
                     ['es-NI', 'Nicaragua'],
                     ['es-PA', 'Panamá'],
                     ['es-PY', 'Paraguay'],
                     ['es-PE', 'Perú'],
                     ['es-PR', 'Puerto Rico'],
                     ['es-DO', 'República Dominicana'],
                     ['es-UY', 'Uruguay'],
                     ['es-VE', 'Venezuela']],
 ['Euskara',         ['eu-ES']],
 ['Français',        ['fr-FR']],
 ['Galego',          ['gl-ES']],
 ['Hrvatski',        ['hr_HR']],
 ['IsiZulu',         ['zu-ZA']],
 ['Íslenska',        ['is-IS']],
 ['Italiano',        ['it-IT', 'Italia'],
                     ['it-CH', 'Svizzera']],
 ['Magyar',          ['hu-HU']],
 ['Nederlands',      ['nl-NL']],
 ['Norsk bokmål',    ['nb-NO']],
 ['Polski',          ['pl-PL']],
 ['Português',       ['pt-BR', 'Brasil'],
                     ['pt-PT', 'Portugal']],
 ['Română',          ['ro-RO']],
 ['Slovenčina',      ['sk-SK']],
 ['Suomi',           ['fi-FI']],
 ['Svenska',         ['sv-SE']],
 ['Türkçe',          ['tr-TR']],
 ['български',       ['bg-BG']],
 ['Pусский',         ['ru-RU']],
 ['Српски',          ['sr-RS']],
 ['한국어',            ['ko-KR']],
 ['中文',             ['cmn-Hans-CN', '普通话 (中国大陆)'],
                     ['cmn-Hans-HK', '普通话 (香港)'],
                     ['cmn-Hant-TW', '中文 (台灣)'],
                     ['yue-Hant-HK', '粵語 (香港)']],
 ['日本語',           ['ja-JP']],
 ['Lingua latīna',   ['la']]];
```

[Web Speech API Demonstration](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)

Reference:

[What are the supported languages for Web Speech API in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733537/what-are-the-supported-languages-for-web-speech-api-in-html5)

I suggest you also check the browser compatibility of web speech API.

Comment: Does that page use the API that OP linked to? It appears to use Google's own.